# Array of Textures in Java

Tags: java, arrays, textures, libgdx

I have this (works fine):

```
public static Texture bubble1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Bubble1.png"));
public static Texture bubble2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Bubble2.png"));
public static Texture bubble3 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Bubble3.png"));
public static Texture bubble4 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Bubble4.png"));
```

And i try it (do not work in any way):

```
String fileName;
Texture[] bubble;
bubble = new Texture[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    fileName = String.format("Bubble%1d", i+1);
    bubble[i] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
}
```

What is wrong? What can I do to make this work while maintaining the simplicity and generality of the code?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot **.png**?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    fileName = String.format("Bubble%1d.png", i+1);
    bubble[i] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Bubble%d.png" or "Bubble%1$d.png"?

Comment: It depends on your task.